# Install node.js on Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, node.js

I need to install node.js on Windows Server 2008. When I try to install Node.js Version 6.10.0, I get this message:

> This application is only supported on Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, or higher

Is there a way to get around this limitation ?

I don't find information about which are the system requirements for the different node versions, and what would be the node version that would run on Windows Server 2008 (not R2).

Comment: I would suggest go with previous releases. https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: @MrRaspberry Thank you. What will be the implications for the compatibility between packages? Will npm take care of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 2008, you have to install the node.js 4.x LTS version. Currently it's node.js 4.8.0.

To my surprise, all the modules installed in the same version with node.js 4.x and node.js 6.x. Even though, ES6 is not supported entirely, important features like arrow functions are supported.